# How to change this to make the text content of the span element change

Tags: random

I tried to find a way to choose randomly through the choices in the array, but it isn't printing. Sorry if this is a simple problem, I just want a quick fix.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Plane</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Your plane</h1>
        <br> <button id="btn" class="button">Click to find out plane</button>
        <h2><span id="spn" class="span"></span></h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    background-color: #333;
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    background-color: #786;
    color: black;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

button:hover {
    border: 2px solid #578;
}
```

```
const btnElement = document.querySelector(".button");
const spnElement = document.querySelector(".span");
const choices = ["Cessna 172p", "F22", "F14", "Boeing 747"];

function choose(choices) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
    return choices[index];
};

btnElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
    spnElement.textContent = choose();
});
```

This is my current code, I think it might be a problem with how I'm calling the function but I'm not sure.

Comment: Replace `var` with `let` when you define variables. Also, you are not passing `choices` when you call `choose()`.